# call a function in case of httpClient timeout in Angular

Tags: angular, timeout, httpclient

I have a function sending a few requests on the server with a timeout each like:

```
this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: headers })
        .timeout(30000)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => {
                ...
            },
            error => {
                ...
            }
                ...
            );
```

In case of timeout (30s), everyone request gets canceled, which is understandable. 
My problem is, that in case of a timeout, the canceled request is not seen as an error, so it doesn't go to the error-part of the request.
Are there any possibilities to call a function in this case?

Comment: because it triggers after the timeout finishes regardless the outcome.
in this case try to check the response based on what you expected or remove timeout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Angular 6, the way to go with the timeout handling is `pipe/timeout`, please look at this example:

```
this.http.get('https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000')
  .pipe(timeout(1000))
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log('forceTimeout', response);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Error', error);
    this.error = error.constructor.name;
  })
```

This fragment is from this example I wrote to demonstrate HTTP Interceptors: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my-http-interceptor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts