# Angular: How to show something on slow HTTP response

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular-http-interceptors

In my angular apps, I want to show a text/modal that have a **cancel** and **reload** button, when the server responds slowly.

If the user click cancel, current http request will be cancelled. If the user click reload, current http request will be retried. If the text/modal already shown and the HTTP request already respond/completed, then the text/modal should disappear.

I have an idea using HTTP interceptor, RxJS, and global service, but implementing it is not that easy.

Is there anyone who have an idea, how to do this the right way?

EDIT: Oh and I want to make it a generic module so every http request can be cancellable or reloadable. So every page could have this functionality

Comment: can you create a stackblitz on what you have tried till now?

Comment: I am sorry, no. Still trying some idea. What I do currently is using a service which have onCancel and onReload observables. And from Interceptor try to subscribe from those observables. I need others' opinion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cancel/abort all pending HTTP requests with `takeUntil`

You can use `takeUntil` to stop an ongoing request, because a request from `HttpClient` returns an observable you can do it quite easy:

#### TS

```
userStop$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

makeRequest() {
    this.userStop$.next(false);
    // Service Call
    this.apiService.makeRequest().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.userStop$)
    ).subscribe(...);
}

handleUserStop() {
    this.userStop$.next(true);
}
```

When you change the `userStop$` to true with a button click for example it will stop. To retry you can simply recall the service method and set the `userStop$` to false;

If you want to retry the request after it failed, you can use `retry(x)`.

```
this.apiService.makeRequest().pipe(
    //retry 2 times on error
    retry(2)
).subscribe(...);
```

You can also checkout this: [How to cancel/unsubscribe all pending HTTP requests angular 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068908/how-to-cancel-unsubscribe-all-pending-http-requests-angular-4)

For more information: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html

Comment: I already have a code similar to this. But is there any way, for each http request, to count the time it tooks for getting response, and then show the user the option to cancel or redo the request observable stream.

Comment: Cancel a request will obviously finish the observable. For those you can use a `Subject` to constantly push new requests, but getting a `404` or a timeout will always finish the observable, because of a throwing error. You need to setup a fallback value in case of an error.

Comment: Other than that your discription looks a bit unclear what you really want. Using takeUntil should achive what you want: The user can retry the request and cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your request will take 20 sec to complete response  then you able to cancel that within 20 sec

By Simply `UnSubscription` That request

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

    export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        private subscription: Subscription;
        ngOnInit() {
            this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe();
        }
        ngOnDestroy() {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }



     cancel() {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

    retry() {
            this.subscription.subscribe();
        }



    }
```

***html*** 
 You can a popup when or any place which button when you make any http request so able to cancel it

```
     <div> {{ subscription | async }}</div>
.
.
.Enter your other logic
.


    <button (click)=="cancel()" > Cancel Request</button>
    <button (click)=="retry()" > Cancel retry</button>
```

Comment: I do not want to just unsubscribe/cancel though. I want the give the user a choice to cancel or retry after a period of time

Comment: @same way you can create retry method dear

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [reportProgress](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#reportProgress) of HttpRequest. There is an explanation how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47034525/9590251. But keep in mind that it will listen to every change detection, thus slowing down app performance a lot. It it recommended to use for a heavy requests (ie file uploading)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create a cancelable subscription**

That one is easy. Create a property in the component like this:

`dataSubscription: Subscription`

and in the event handler where you fire the request, create it like this:

`dataSubscription = someService.someRESTApiCalls.subscribe(....)`

any time, you want to stop this, you can call

`this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe()`

I also recommend to utilize the `ngOnDestroy` hook, and unsubscribe from it if needed:

```
ngOnDestroy(){

   if(this.dataSubscription) this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

to cancel the call.

2. **Modals**

For modals, I recommend the [Angular Material Modal](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

3. **Logic**

Create a class property in the component `isResponseArrived: boolean` or something. After the user initiates the request, in the event handler set it to false, and show whatever you want to shuw, with an `ngIf="!isResponseArrived"`˛ After the response arrived, modify the flags value to true in the subscription reponse handler (both with value, or on error).

+1: **detect if the subscription is taking too long**

Use the httpClient timeout ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187081/call-a-function-in-case-of-httpclient-timeout-in-angular)):

```
this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: headers })
        .timeout(30000)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => {
                ...
            },
            error => {
                ...
            }
                ...
            );
```

Comment: How to detect if the subscription taking longer than x seconds?? And after I know that the respond take a long time, I can cancel or reload it.

Comment: Doesn't timeout automatically errored/completed the stream? Is there any way to not to complete the stream? Let the client still waiting for response but at the same time, user get the notification that the current http is taking a long time and could cancel or redo it.